# Building guess the animal game

Tags: php, sql

For a uni assignment I have to create a webpage that the user can answer yes/no question and the system will guess the animal they are thinking of. The database had to a self referencing table/binary tree.

I have built the database which seems to be working fine.

The columns are

nodeID, parentID, message, answerYesID, answerNoID. The parentID, and two answerIds are all fk refering to the nodeID.

using PHP I have created buttons and a function that retrieves the first node and ask the first question. I have also got to the point where the system asks the next appropriate question. This is where I am stuck. I have tried various ways of switch and if statements but I am struggling to traverse throught the binary tree properly.

I have created a variable $currentnode which I would use to keep track of where the user is so the correct questions can be asked, but, using this in the next if block causes the system to jump ahead.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
$query = "SELECT `message`, `nodeID` FROM `creature`";//basic query that will be used at                    all times
$where = "";//empty where clause, will be altered 



//function created to be re used after an answer is given
function output($query,$where,$dbconn){
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query.$where);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
echo "{$row['message']}
    {$row['nodeID']}<br>";


 echo '<form action="play.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">yes
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="0">no
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">
<input type = "submit" name = "restart" value = "restart game">
</form>';}



?>



<form action="play.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="Start Game">
</form>


<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['start'] ))
{ 
$where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '1'";
$currentnode = '1';
output($query,$where,$dbconn);
}



 if ($currentnode = 1){
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] )){

            switch ($_POST['answer']) {

                case 1:     $where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '2'";
                                    output($query,$where,$dbconn);
                            $currentnode = 2; 
                            break;  

                case 0:     $where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '25'";
                              output($query,$where,$dbconn);
                            $currentnode = 25;
                            break;


                            }   

                    }           
}

if ($currentnode = 2){
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] )){

            switch ($_POST['answer']) {

                case 1:     $where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '3'";
                             output($query,$where,$dbconn);
                            $currentnode = 3; 
                            break;  

                case 2:     $where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '4'";
                             output($query,$where,$dbconn);
                            $currentnode = 4;
                            break;


                            }   

                    }           
}   





if ( isset( $_POST['restart'] ))
{ 

$where = "WHERE `nodeID` = '1'";
output($query,$where, $dbconn);
}
```

Comment: Good assignment.  Lots to learn!

Comment: Yes, but I am really struggling!